# How to make different state updates synchronous in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, setstate

I have a component which has two state variables:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(true);

const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsDataLoading(true);
    const fetchedHugeData = await hugeDataFetch();
    setData({ ...fetchedHugeData });
    setIsDataLoading(false);
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
},[aVariable]);

return [isDataLoading, data];
```

In the above code, the `setIsDataLoading(false)` is getting executed even before `setData()` finished in the previous line.

How can I make sure that not happen?

Comment: No, it's not being executed before the previous line. How can you tell it is?

Comment: (You'll probably just want to use [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/): `const dataSWR = useSWR(['hugeData', aVariable], hugeDataFetch); const {data} = dataSWR; const isDataLoading = data === undefined;`)

Comment: @AKX why? Adding a new library to solve a problem (that can be easily solved) just adds more complexity to an app that doesn't need to be there. And then you just have one more thing to debug if it goes wrong or you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Andy To not reinvent the wheel. `swr` solves this sort of thing very elegantly (as you can see above), without having to faff around with effects, thinking about loading states, etc, etc. (Also, it has no deps of its own and a bundle size effect of 10kb.)

Comment: @AKX do you not think that swr is a reinvention of _this_ wheel? :)

Comment: @Andy TBH, no – if this was a simple wheel, this question wouldn't be necessary. :)

Comment: There is no need to sync by yourself. Just perform work based on these two states. E.g. If `isDataLoading` is `true`, show a loading UI, if the data exists, consume the data. You also need to add an error state to hold the data fetching error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *ghybs* said, state updates are asynchronous, therefore the best solution would be to use another `useEffect` that listens to `data` and, if not null, calls `setIsDataLoading`.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(true);

const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsDataLoading(true);
    const fetchedHugeData = await hugeDataFetch();
    setData({ ...fetchedHugeData });
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [aVariable]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        setIsDataLoading(false);
    }
}, [data])

return [isDataLoading, data];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another useEffect  to view the data state.The code should look like this.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(true);

const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsDataLoading(true);
    const fetchedHugeData = await hugeDataFetch();
    setData({ ...fetchedHugeData });
  //  setIsDataLoading(false); 
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
},[aVariable]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== null) { setIsDataLoading(false); }
}, [data])


return [isDataLoading, data];
```

Answer (score 1):

May Be this could work for you...!
Simply need to check if your function is returning your data or not...
If your returns something and is executed successfully then only it will update your response and set your state data.

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(true);

const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsDataLoading(true);
    hugeDataFetch().then((_yourResponse) => {
        setData({ ..._yourResponse });
        setIsDataLoading(false);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [aVariable]);

return [isDataLoading, data];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

To ensure that the state updates are executed synchronously in React, you can use the await keyword before calling setData() in the fetchData function. This will ensure that the state update is completed before moving on to the next line of code.

Here's the updated code with the await keyword:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isDataLoading, setIsDataLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsDataLoading(true);
    const fetchedHugeData = await hugeDataFetch();
    await setData({ ...fetchedHugeData }); // Use await here
    setIsDataLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [aVariable]);

  return [isDataLoading, data];
}
```

By adding await before setData({ ...fetchedHugeData }), the setIsDataLoading(false) will not be executed until the state update operation of setData is finished.

Keep in mind that when using await within an async function, the function itself should be marked as async. In this case, the fetchData function is marked as async.

With this change, the state updates will be executed synchronously, ensuring that setIsDataLoading(false) will not run until the state update operation of setData is completed.